# confirm/window.confirm not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have some Javascript using the confirm method; it works fine in Chrome and Firefox and even in IE 11 but not in IE 8. Nothing happens at all when using confirm or window.confirm. Is confirm compatable with IE 8? If not what would be a comparable way to do this?

```
confirm("Do you want to continue?");
```

This is being called from an onclick event.

Comment: Yes, it is compatible with IE8. Are you sure the problem isn't elsewhere? (F12)

Comment: Yes, confirm works in IE8.  Chances are that you have some other error that is getting in the way of this code getting parsed or run.

Comment: Good thoughts; this is being called from an onclick event. Any compatibility issues there?

Comment: Can you show us more of your code so we can try to work it out?